# Now that python 2 is deprecated, do we still need to use the venv for creating virtual environment?

Tags: python, virtual-environment

Can we now skip creating virtual environments using venv, since only version 3 of python will now be available in most cases?

From python docs it states

> Creating a virtual environment venv (for Python 3) and virtualenv (for
>   Python 2) allow you to manage separate package installations for
>   different projects. They essentially allow you to create a “virtual”
>   isolated Python installation and install packages into that virtual
>   installation.

The venv module provides support for creating lightweight “virtual environments” with their own site directories, optionally isolated from system site directories. Each virtual environment has its own Python binary (which matches the version of the binary that was used to create this environment) and can have its own independent set of installed Python packages in its site directories.

**Is there any use case, where we would like to keep the directories isolated from system site directories, since now only one version of python will be there?**

Comment: Most definitely. I work on a handful of different projects every week, and some of those might depend on different versions of the same libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Python applications will often use packages and modules that don’t come as part of the standard library. Applications will sometimes need a specific version of a library, because the application may require that a particular bug has been fixed or the application may be written using an obsolete version of the library’s interface.

This means it may not be possible for one Python installation to meet the requirements of every application. If application A needs version 1.0 of a particular module but application B needs version 2.0, then the requirements are in conflict and installing either version 1.0 or 2.0 will leave one application unable to run.

The solution for this problem is to create a virtual environment.

SEE this: 
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: actually I am coming from node background, in node, if an application requires some specific version of a library, then we have it installed locally and local version will be used instead of the globally installed version

Comment: however I am not getting surity about your answer because, I understand that python venv is for keeping version of python and not versions of libraries, and mostly other thought I am having is that either python 3.3. or 3.7 will not be having any breaking changes

Comment: No, dear it is for library too. I have added a link to my answer. Have a look at it.

Comment: Don't forget to mark answer correct if you find it helpful.

Comment: Thank you, Jai, reading that documentation, I agree with your point.